# Ftp Application Chilkat Ftp2 Does Not Start ERR CLR20r3

Tags: vb.net, ftp, chilkat

In some cases I've encoutered this problem on some machines; apllication doesn't start with no msg or sometimes with Windows crash errors. I think depends on some framework component, but really I don't know how to resolve. I've already verified Visual C++ Redist Presence (2017). Can you help me? I've just looked at Windows Registry Event and there are 2 error events; I've attached following.
Any ideas? I use ftp2 ChilkatDotNet4.dll version 9.5.0.68

```
=======================================
Eventi Errore FTP

Nome registro: Application
Origine:       .NET Runtime
Data:          18/07/2018 16:46:51
ID evento:     1026
Categoria attività:Nessuna
Livello:       Errore
Parole chiave: Classico
Utente:        N/D
Computer:      ETagliabue-PC
Descrizione:
Applicazione: PigrecoFTP.exe
Versione framework: v4.0.30319
Descrizione: il processo è stato terminato a causa di un'eccezione non gestita.
Informazioni sull'eccezione: System.BadImageFormatException
   in PigrecoFTP.mFTP.Main()
   in PigrecoFTP.fLogo..ctor()

Informazioni sull'eccezione: System.InvalidOperationException
   in PigrecoFTP.My.MyProject+MyForms.Create__Instance__[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.__Canon)
   in PigrecoFTP.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm()
   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(System.String[])
   in PigrecoFTP.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])


========================================================

Nome registro: Application
Origine:       Application Error
Data:          18/07/2018 16:46:51
ID evento:     1000
Categoria attività:(100)
Livello:       Errore
Parole chiave: Classico
Utente:        N/D
Computer:      ETagliabue-PC
Descrizione:
Nome dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: PigrecoFTP.exe, versione: 2.1.1.0, timestamp: 0x5b29fefa
Nome del modulo che ha generato l'errore: KERNELBASE.dll, versione: 10.0.17134.165, timestamp: 0xfa43f4b2
Codice eccezione: 0xe0434352
Offset errore 0x0010ddc2
ID processo che ha generato l'errore: 0x2514
Ora di avvio dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: 0x01d41ea629d4fcc3
Percorso dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: C:\Pigreco 2.1\PigrecoFTP.exe
Percorso del modulo che ha generato l'errore: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
ID segnalazione: 0ada4e60-4e0b-43fc-b86e-f13c3d332488
Nome completo pacchetto che ha generato l'errore:
ID applicazione relativo al pacchetto che ha generato l'errore:
XML evento:

    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
      <System>
        <Provider Name="Application Error" />
        <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>100</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-07-18T14:46:51.940619500Z" />
        <EventRecordID>9008</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>ETagliabue-PC</Computer>
        <Security />
      </System>
      <EventData>
        <Data>PigrecoFTP.exe</Data>
        <Data>2.1.1.0</Data>
        <Data>5b29fefa</Data>
        <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
        <Data>10.0.17134.165</Data>
        <Data>fa43f4b2</Data>
        <Data>e0434352</Data>
        <Data>0010ddc2</Data>
        <Data>2514</Data>
        <Data>01d41ea629d4fcc3</Data>
        <Data>C:\Pigreco 2.1\PigrecoFTP.exe</Data>
        <Data>C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
        <Data>0ada4e60-4e0b-43fc-b86e-f13c3d332488</Data>
        <Data>
        </Data>
        <Data>
        </Data>
      </EventData>
    </Event>

===================================================

Nome registro: Application
Origine:       Windows Error Reporting
Data:          18/07/2018 16:47:04
ID evento:     1001
Categoria attività:Nessuna
Livello:       Informazioni
Parole chiave: Classico
Utente:        N/D
Computer:      ETagliabue-PC
Descrizione:
Bucket errato 1422329624855657611, tipo 5
Nome evento: CLR20r3
Risposta: Non disponibile
ID CAB: 0

Firma problema:
P1: PigrecoFTP.exe
P2: 2.1.1.0
P3: 5b29fefa
P4: PigrecoFTP
P5: 2.1.1.0
P6: 5b29fefa
P7: c9
P8: c
P9: System.InvalidOperationException
P10:

File allegati:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF0A4.tmp.mdmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF289.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF2AA.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF2A8.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF2C8.tmp.txt

I file potrebbero essere disponibili qui:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_PigrecoFTP.exe_34f9c1645f3274f7fd82cee797602cbfb31baa9a_0989035a_3c1d22df

Simbolo analisi:
Nuova ricerca di soluzioni: 0
ID rapporto: 0ada4e60-4e0b-43fc-b86e-f13c3d332488
Stato rapporto: 2147487744
Bucket con hash: 0d7268abdbc332eec3bd21420b093c8b
GUID CAB: 0
XML evento:

    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
      <System>
        <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" />
        <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID>
        <Level>4</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-07-18T14:47:04.981973000Z" />
        <EventRecordID>9011</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer>ETagliabue-PC</Computer>
        <Security />
      </System>
      <EventData>
        <Data>1422329624855657611</Data>
        <Data>5</Data>
        <Data>CLR20r3</Data>
        <Data>Non disponibile</Data>
        <Data>0</Data>
        <Data>PigrecoFTP.exe</Data>
        <Data>2.1.1.0</Data>
        <Data>5b29fefa</Data>
        <Data>PigrecoFTP</Data>
        <Data>2.1.1.0</Data>
        <Data>5b29fefa</Data>
        <Data>c9</Data>
        <Data>c</Data>
        <Data>System.InvalidOperationException</Data>
        <Data>
        </Data>
        <Data>
    \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF0A4.tmp.mdmp
    \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF289.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
    \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF2AA.tmp.xml
    \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF2A8.tmp.csv
    \\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF2C8.tmp.txt</Data>
        <Data>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_PigrecoFTP.exe_34f9c1645f3274f7fd82cee797602cbfb31baa9a_0989035a_3c1d22df</Data>
        <Data>
        </Data>
        <Data>0</Data>
        <Data>0ada4e60-4e0b-43fc-b86e-f13c3d332488</Data>
        <Data>2147487744</Data>
        <Data>0d7268abdbc332eec3bd21420b093c8b</Data>
        <Data>0</Data>
      </EventData>
    </Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `System.BadImageFormatException` is thrown when a process is trying to load a dependency that has a different bitness compared to the process itself. This could be a 32-bit process trying to load a 64-bit DLL, or a 64-bit process trying to load a 32-bit DLL.

Chilkat isn't compiled as AnyCPU, but instead contains two DLLs (one 32-bit and one 64-bit). This means that if you really want to compile your application as AnyCPU you have to ship it with both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of the `ChilkatDotNet4.dll`, and have the installer install both of them into the [Global Assembly Cache (GAC)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6507942).

If you cannot/don't want to do it this way, the alternatives are:

1. Compile your application as 32-bit only.
2. Do the same as Chilkat and release two versions of your application: one 32-bit and one 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

The BadImageFormatException is the "Common Error #1" described here:  http://www.chilkatsoft.com/x64_Framework4.asp

Also, the ChilkatDotNet4.dll is the assembly one would use with the .NET 4.0 Framework.  It would require the MSVC 2010 runtime redist to be installed on the system, which it probably already is..      See http://cknotes.com/chilkat-net-assemblies-matching-visual-studio-versions-to-net-framework-versions-to-vc-runtime-versions/